# Customizing ActionBarSherlock - disabling back/home button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using custom layout for an action bar, using the following code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);
```

However, it keeps showing some fragment of the action bar which is not the custom action bar I've created:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was enough to get it working (instead of all the lines I quoted in the question details):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);
```